# Android View Pager and RecycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I just want to display a list using recycle view inside the view pager. (ex. just like android home page icons)
But here list is not showing and without view pager it works.

Please can anyone tell me where is the problem... 
Thank you..

activity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

obj_tile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="Group Title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

-fragment_screen_slide_page.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PageViewer Title" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    List<TilePojo> tilePojoList=new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);


        /*Context context=MainActivity.this;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, null);
        RecyclerView rvTiles = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            TilePojo tilePojo = new TilePojo(R.drawable.apple, "Button Title " + i);
            tilePojoList.add(tilePojo);
        }

        TileAdapter adapter = new TileAdapter(tilePojoList);
        if(adapter!=null) {
            rvTiles.setAdapter(adapter);
            rvTiles.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        }
*/



    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
            // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            // Otherwise, select the previous step.
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    }


    /**
     * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 ScreenSlidePageFragment objects, in
     * sequence.
     */
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }

}
```

-ScreenSlidePageFragment.java

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

    List<TilePojo> tilePojoList=new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, null);
        RecyclerView rvTiles = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            TilePojo tilePojo = new TilePojo(R.drawable.apple, "Button Title " + i);
            tilePojoList.add(tilePojo);
        }

        TileAdapter adapter = new TileAdapter(tilePojoList);
        if(adapter!=null) {
            rvTiles.setAdapter(adapter);
            rvTiles.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this.getActivity(), 2));
        }


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

TileAdapter.java

```
public class TileAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TileAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<TilePojo> list;

    public TileAdapter(List<TilePojo> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public TileAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Inflate the custom layout
        View tileView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.obj_tile, parent, false);

        // Return a new holder instance
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(tileView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TileAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TilePojo tilePojo=list.get(position);

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(tilePojo.getSrc());
        holder.nameTextView.setText(tilePojo.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // Your holder should contain a member variable
        // for any view that will be set as you render a row
        public TextView nameTextView;
        public ImageView imageView;

        // We also create a constructor that accepts the entire item row
        // and does the view lookups to find each subview
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            // Stores the itemView in a public final member variable that can be used
            // to access the context from any ViewHolder instance.
            super(itemView);

            nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give some code that you've tried?

Comment: Show the code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: have you used scrollview in any layout?

Comment: No I didn't use scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.. 
I just replace the following (@ScreenSlidePageFragment.java)

```
rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
```

Thank you.